# Can run app from terminal but not from menu in XFCE

Tags: launcher, xfce, appmenu

I have an app which I can run from the terminal in this way

```
python3 /home/me/path/to/my_app.py
```

It works fine.

To make it easier for other people I want to use the *Menu Editor* to create a launcher for this. I have done this hundreds of times in the past for other apps, but this one fails and I don't know why. This is my setup:

[image]

If I enable *Run in terminal* the terminal is opened for some milliseconds and then it closes, probably because of an error but there is no time to read what is going on. If I copy-paste the command into a terminal it works fine.

Comment: Check if a working directory needs to be set for your application

Comment: I have tried but it does not change anything. I tried both the location of the script and the home directory.

Comment: Try adding the full path to python

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3 ...`should work, as vanadium suggests

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3 /home/tct/code/repos/PyticularsTCT/scripts/tct_graphic_interface.py` is the same issue. Copy/pasting this into a terminal works fine.